# Replacing Socket.ReceiveAsync with NetworkStream.ReadAsync (awaitable)

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, networkstream, async-await

I have an application that makes a couple hundred TCP connections at the same time, and receives a constant stream of data from them.

```
 private void startReceive()
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        e.Completed += receiveCompleted;
        e.SetBuffer(new byte[1024], 0, 1024);
        if (!Socket.ReceiveAsync(e)) { receiveCompleted(this, e); }  
    }

    void receiveCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessData(e);

        if (!Socket.ReceiveAsync(e)) { receiveCompleted(this, e); }
    }
```

My attempts led to something like this:

```
private async void StartReceive()
    {
        byte[] Buff = new byte[1024];
        int recv = 0;
        while (Socket.Connected)
        {
            recv = await NetworkStream.ReadAsync(Buff, 0, 1024);
            ProcessData(Buff,recv);
        }
    }
```

The issue I had was the method calling `StartReceive()` would block, and not get to the accompanying `StartSend() method called after`StartReceive()`. Creating a new task for`StartReceive()`would just end up with 300-ish threads, and it seems to do so just by calling`StartReceive()` anyways.

What would be the correct method of implementing the new `async` and `await` keywords on my existing code while using a `NetworkStream` so it is using the thread pool that `Socket.SendAsync()` and `Socket.ReceiveAsync()` are using to avoid having to have hundreds of threads/tasks?

Is there any performance advantage of using `networkstream` in this manner over i/o completion ports with `beginreceive`?

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is, or the context - you talk about the calling method blocking... what's it blocking on? Isn't that the problem you need to fix? Please clarify your question - as well as indicating whether all of the real "work" has any thread affinity (e.g. to the UI thread).

Comment: Well the main issue is, the version using await NetworkStream.ReadAsync causes the application to create one thread per connection. Where as using Socket.ReceiveAsync seems to hover under 30 threads for all 300 connections.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're changing two things at once here: the asynchronous style (`SocketAsyncEventArgs` to `Task`/`async`) and the level of abstraction (`Socket` to `NetworkStream`).

Since you're already comfortable with `Socket`, I recommend just changing the asynchronous style, and continue using the `Socket` class directly.

The Async CTP doesn't give `Socket` any `async`-compatible methods (which is weird; I assume they were left out by mistake and will be added in .NET 4.5).

It's not that hard to create your own `ReceiveAsyncTask` extension method (and similar wrappers for other operations) if you use my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/):

```
public static Task<int> ReceiveAsyncTask(this Socket socket,
    byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
{
  return AsyncFactory<int>.FromApm(socket.BeginReceive, socket.EndReceive,
      buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

Once you do that, your `StartReceive` can be written as such:

```
private async Task StartReceive()
{
  try
  {
    var buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (true)
    {
      var bytesReceived = await socket.ReceiveAsyncTask(buffer, 0, 1024)
          .ConfigureAwait(false);
      ProcessData(buffer, bytesReceived);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Handle errors here
  }
}
```

Now, to address many minor points:

- `await` doesn't spawn a new thread. I wrote up [an async/await intro on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), as have many others. `async`/`await` allows concurrency, but that doesn't necessarily imply multithreading.
- Hundreds of *threads* can be problematic. Hundreds of *tasks*, though, are not a problem at all; the thread pool and BCL are designed to handle many, many tasks.
- `async`/`await` is not a brand new form of asynchronous processing; it's just an *easier way* to *express* asynchronous processing. It still uses IOCPs underneath.  `async`/`await` has slightly lower performance than the lower-level methods; its appeal is the ease of writing and composing asynchronous methods.
- A very busy system can see some increased GC pressure when it switches to `async`/`await`. Stephen Toub on the Parallel Team [wrote up some example socket-specific awaitables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) that can help with that issue. (I recommend using the straightforward pattern first, and only using the performance-enhanced approach if you find it necessary; still, it's good to know it's out there if you do end up needing it).
- Async methods should return `Task` unless you really *need* them to return `void`. `Task` is awaitable, so your method is composable (and more easily testable); `void` is more like "fire and forget".
- You can call `ConfigureAwait(false)` to tell the rest of the `async` method to execute on a thread pool thread. I use this in my example above so that `ProcessData` is executed in a thread pool thread, just like it was when using `SocketAsyncEventArgs`.
- `Socket.Connected` is useless. [You need to send data to detect if the connection is still valid.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html)

Comment: Thanks for a lot of this useful information. And I know, I was just using Socket.Connected for a quick write up.

Comment: Has this been implemented in .Net 4.5?

Comment: @Isaac: No. I think the BCL team decided it would just lead to too many APIs for the `Socket` type.